# Two Macs signed into Google with same IP address

Tags: security, accounts, google

I don't know if this goes here or somewhere else, but it's about my Mac, so I'll post it here.

I got an e-mail saying my Google account was signed into on a Mac. I looked at the location and IP of said Mac, and it matches the only Mac that I have. The strange thing is, it shows two separate devices for my Mac. The only difference between the devices is the browser: the one that it says I'm using is using Chrome 52.0, and the other one is using Chrome 35.0.

Is this a bug, or is something wrong? Is there a way to remove this "second" Mac from my devices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but - could you be signed-in in two different browsers?

Comment: @TMHahn You reminded me: I forgot to put in the difference between the computers (the browser version). My bad! :) I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you recently updated Google Chrome using the built-in updater (available from `chrome://help/`), that could cause Google to recognize two different browsers.  If you haven't updated Chrome, or just want to go through the process:

Click on the Google Account icon in the upper right-hand corner of your Gmail window and click on the My Account link.

From there, choose Sign-In & Security, scroll down to Recently Used Devices and click on Review devices (aka the Devices & Activity page as described in [Google's Security support article](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3067630)).

Click on Secure Your Account and follow the various prompts; you'll be signed out of your Google account and required to re-enter your password or possibly authenticate via 2FA, if you already had that enabled.

After you have logged back in, return to the Recently Used Devices to verify only one browser.

Comment: I followed your steps, but I don't see an option to verify only one browser. Where is that? Thanks for the answer, BTW! :)